# Is there any way to migrate the built-in usergrid db

Tags: cassandra, apigee, usergrid

I've been running usergrid-stack commit 08f26cc865c96185d11990bf622730beff59971a for a while using the built-in cassandra db.
I need to migrate to another server and thought I'd take the chance to update.

I tried copying the folder standalone/target/tmp to the new installation but doing so gives me the error below.

```
null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=hinted_handoff_throttle_delay_in_ms for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@6b7b9f29; Unable to find property 'hinted_handoff_throttle_delay_in_ms' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
Invalid yaml; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.
```

Is there any way to migrate the db to a newer version?

If not, is there at least a way to migrate the db using the old version?

Answer (score 0):

iirc `hinted_handoff_throttle_delay_in_ms` is a setting from Cassandra 1.1 which was removed in Cassandra 1.2 so you might need to edit the conf file (`cassandra.yaml`) and remove this setting.